# Address in windows style in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Ruby learning book I read
" .... The File.join method is simple to use, and it allows you to write the same code to run on both systems rather than choosing between backslashes and forward slashes in your code."

but for example in windowos when I type 
File.join( "c:" , "dir2" , "dir3" , "a.txt" ) Ruby returns me  "c:/dir2/dir3/a.txt"
Whereas I expect "c:\dir2\dir3\a.txt".
knoW how can I produce an absolute address in windows style ( with backslash ) .
thanks

Comment: For your information, Windows is able to use strings like `c:/dir2/dir3/a.txt` without any errors. Some 3rd-party programs might fail, but depending on what you are doing in a program, the difference between / and \ is only cosmetic.

Answer (score 2):

`File.join('c:','dir1', 'dir2').gsub(File::SEPARATOR, File::ALT_SEPARATOR || File::SEPARATOR)`